# Android Consistent Crash - NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I have tested my app on numerous devices and this never happens, but when I look in my Android Developer Console, I am seeing a lot of these:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.MyApp/com.MyApp.ProductMain}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1696)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1716)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:124)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:968)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3806)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.MyApp.ProductMain.onCreate(Unknown Source)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1660)
... 11 more
```

To me, this really doesnt tell me much, but maybe someone can read this better than I???

Comment: Are you running a debug build? You should get a line number in the com.MyApp.ProductMain line near the bottom, which shows you where your exception is happening

Comment: kindly link your onCreate() code please. Otherwise we can't tell what is giving you null pointer exception

Comment: This error was taken from the Android Developer Console under reported crashes for the live app.  So no, it is not a debug build...this is how google is reporting it to me.

Comment: You should check what object could be null on com.MyApp.ProductMain.onCreate(). It'd help if you share code from that method.

Comment: @Jesse There is something that is null. use debugger to find out which line is giving you this error. Or better post error.

Comment: are you using any public  folders , we had one crash because on some phones Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) returned null

Answer (score 1):

What I've discovered after publishing my app on Google Play, is that there is a whole lot of errors specific to a phone manufacturer, or even specific model. Some phone models require extra permissions to do stuff, some crash at a point where others runs without any problems.
I use two app crash tracking systems: [Bugsense](http://www.bugsense.com) and [ACRA](http://code.google.com/p/acra/) they give much more detailed reports than the developer console, like device model, features, Android version, detailed stack traces, etc.. From there you can see which specific devices are failing and debug on them.